# Gabriel Graph Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I try to program the Gabriel graph algorithm, in my program I have a problem concerning the calculation of distance between μ (α β center) and other nodes of the graph and compare it with the distance between α and μ . the question is how to calculate the distance between μ and the other vertices.
the following image, I look for example to calculate the distance in yellow

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're representing the points as `(x,y)` coordinates, just search up `distance formula`. It's very simple.

Comment: It is a good idea, I think I have to use the coordinates of points and Euclidean distance, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think is verry simple to calculate the distance between  μ (α β center) and point ϒ (for example) by using the points as (x,y) coordinates and distance formula,

[image]

μ(x,y)={(x(α)+x(β))/2,(y(α)+y(β))/2}